# jquery 1.5 problem with append jscript file

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

hi guys this code was working on jquery 1.4.4 well

```
$(function(){
    $("head").append("<script src='jscript/helpdesk/core/classes/members.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");

var chkMember = $.validate_memberid();

});
```

but in jquery 1.5 this does'nt work .
i think in 1.4.4 code was waiting for append or know append .js file but 1.5 run codes before script loaded :S
any one know what to do ?

i don't want to use :

```
$.getScript('jscript/helpdesk/core/classes/members.js', function () {
     // do stuffs
});
```

cause i load many js files and unload them with append and remove :(

Comment: I don't think there's such thing as unloading a script?

Comment: Indeed... there's a lot of "why are you doing this?" here...

Comment: i got alot of classes as .js and i don't want to load them all , i load them when i need them and when over i remove it so browser have better performance .

Answer (score 1):

You should check out requireJS http://requirejs.org/

Sounds like you might have a lot dependent scripts, this will help you manage those.